# Weird vertical spacing with inline block and vertical align

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I've got a strange spacing issue on top of inline-block elements when I use vertical-align middle on them. It's like a 2px margin on top that extends the parent container. With the default vertical align no space above the elements occures and the parent container isn't expanded. I created an example to demonstrate the probleme:

http://cdpn.io/BKndk

Thank you for your help.

Comment: vertical-align won't work on inline block elements

Comment: if you want to use vertical alignment, I would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/E78HQ/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are applying vertical-align: middle to the "a" element instead of the parent element, the nav container. If you remove it from the "a" element and add it to your nav class it should work as expected.

Comment: that seems to be doing the trick. thanks!

Comment: You should just remove vertical align altogether!